# Oracle select is fast but cursor fetch is not

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I'm using **Oracle 11.2** and I have a `select` statement inside a cursor that returns ~500 rows. If I run the select by itself it takes 20-30 seconds.
When I do a `FETCH <CUR> BULK COLLECT INTO ...` it takes about 40 minutes to execute.  Any ideas what I might do or that I'm doing wrong that may help speed things up?

```
SELECT m.G_ID, m.S_ID, m.D_ID, m.YYYY, m.MM, m.MIN_DAY, m.MAX_DAY, m.BALANCE, TOTAL_Balance
                    ,FNC_GET_OPEN_TRANACTION_COUNT(mm.G_ID, m.S_ID, m.D_ID) TCOUNT
                    ,FNC_GET_LAST_BALANCE(m.G_ID, m.S_ID, m.D_ID) LAST_BALANCE
                    ,FNC_GET_MAX_TDATE(ms.G_ID, m.S_ID, m.D_ID, 'F') as Max_Date 
FROM VEW_MONTHLY m,
             VEW_OPEN_NEG_GSDS o    
WHERE TOTAL_Balance < 0 and 
                    on m.G_ID = o.g_ID and m.S_ID = o.s_ID and m.D_ID = o.d_Id
```

Comment: `If I run the select by itself it takes 20-30 seconds.` Are you sure that you get all results and not only first 100 records for example?

Comment: did you try explain plan 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231

Comment: Query you posted is invalid. `and on` doesn't look well. But OK, that isn't a problem. You seem to be using two views. Are they correctly written? Could they be optimized? Also, there are 3 functions you're calling - how fast do they return the result? A second per row seems to be *fast*, but 500 rows x one second is ... well, not that *fast*. Try to focus to each of those, one by one, and see whether you can make them run faster. 30 seconds for 500 rows seems way too long (from my point of view). 40 minutes is a disaster.

Comment: I'm working with the DBA to figure it out.  He is looking at the plan and DB resources.